# No releases available for package “pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSNiffer”

Tags: xampp, pear, phpcodesniffer

On windows7 I have installed XAMPP with PEAR. I try install PHP_CodeSniffer but i obtain error No releases available for package “pear.php.net/PHP_CodeSNiffer”.
I try `pear clear_cache, pear update-chanels` but still same error

Answer (score 1):

Did you try both of the command below ?

pear install PHP_CodeSniffer

pear install --alldeps PHP_CodeSniffer

Or try below
pear uninstall php_codesniffer
pear config-set php_dir \xampp\php\pear
pear install php_codesniffer

Or may be you can just download from git repository and use?
https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer